# javascript postMessage event.data come back as a number not a string

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I am having an iframe that is looking to send a simple message to the parent page.  when my parent page function is called I get event.data back but it is a numerical value, not a string.

iframe script

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMessage(){
        var message = "";
        message = "Hello, I am an Iframe that has loaded";
        parent.postMessage(message, '*');
    }
    </script>
```

The script on the html page

```
<script>
function receiveMessage(event){
alert(event.data);
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

</script>
```

event.data comes back as 197.
any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: Is this all there is too it? I just tested your code out in two local html files and it works fine.

Comment: There is pardot iframe that i have the script in.  thats about it.

Comment: I was not calling the method.   Stupid missed step.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the code in iframe as below...

```
<script>
  function sendHeight() {
    var height= document.getElementById('pardot-form').offsetHeight;
    window.parent.postMessage({
     'height':height,
     'location':window.location.href
    }, '*');
  }
  window.onload = sendHeight;
  window.onresize = sendHeight;
</script>
```